# Post apocalyptic movie featuring scantily clad women and traveling vehicles that formed a bubble around them when traveling

Tags: story-identification, movie

I happened to catch this movie probably halfway through but had to leave. I believe it was on Pluto TV. I had the title in my head for a couple of days but lost it. Post apocalyptic, scantily clad women, traveling vehicles formed a bubble around them when traveling.  That's all I caught.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you mean "apocalyptic?"  When did you see this?

Comment: @DavidW It must have been after 2014 considering when Pluto TV launched.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. When you say "formed a bubble" do you mean a literal bubble or are we talking about scifi '*shields*' or something else?

Comment: Have you checked out any listings of movies by The Asylum? I'm guessing a movie like you described would either have been on that channel or Shout Factory's.

Comment: Could use some more specifics; but at a guess I suppose it could be 'Barbarella'. It certainly has the "scantily clad" and "Post apocalyptic" seeming landscape parts covered, and I vaguely recall an ice-sled thing that had a plastic bubble-like enclosure.

Answer (score 16):

The description reminds me a lot of [Nemesis 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemesis_3:_Prey_Harder), the third movie of a low budget Terminator-esque series.

The movie takes place after humanity was enslaved by cyborgs and is very much post apocalypse.

The entire movie is on Youtube and [here](https://youtu.be/yTVPcPIXtps?t=3137) and [here](https://youtu.be/yTVPcPIXtps?t=3675) are timestamps with the bubble effect.